# Discrete Fourier Transform question

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-analysis, convolution, signal-processing, image-processing

Let $R_{M\times N}$ be a space of size $M\times N$. Define the 2D Discrete Fourier Transform of $f\in R_{M\times N}$ to be

\begin{equation}
\tilde{f}[m,n]=\sum_{p=0}^{M-1}\sum_{q=0}^{N-1}f[p,q]e^{\frac{-i 2\pi p m}{M} +\frac{-i2\pi q n}{N}},\ \ \  0\leq m < M,\ \ 0 \leq n < N
\end{equation}

If $f[m,n]$ and $g[m,n]$ are related by a translation i.e. $f[m, n] = g[m + u_0 (mod\ M), n + v_0 (mod\ N)]$ can I say anything special about the rank of the following matrix?

\begin{equation}
H[m,n]= \frac{\tilde{f}[m,n]\tilde{g}[m,n]^*}{|\tilde{f}[m,n]\tilde{g}[m,n]^*|}
\end{equation}

A bit more following AnonSubmitter85's hint: I work out the transform for the space $M$ with shift $u_0(mod\ M)$. We later generalize the result to $M\times N$.

\begin{align}
\tilde{f}[m]&=\sum_{p=0}^{M-1}f[p]e^{\frac{-i 2\pi p m}{M}}\\
&=\sum_{p=0}^{M-1}g[p+u_0(mod\ M)]e^{\frac{-i 2\pi m(p + u_0(mod\ M))}{M}}e^{\frac{i 2\pi mu_0(mod\ M)}{M}}\\
&=\tilde{g}[m]e^{\frac{i 2\pi mu_0(mod\ M)}{M}}
\end{align}

In general, we have $H[m,n]=e^{\frac{i 2\pi mu_0(mod\ M)}{M}}.e^{\frac{i 2\pi nv_0(mod\ N)}{N}}$ I know how to get the rank of matrix through Gaussian elimination but I've no idea how to do it for a general matrix like this. So what is the rank?

Comment: Although I only need the result for m=n, it would be nice to get an answer to the more general version posted above.

Comment: Isn't $H[M,n] = e^{-j2\pi p u_0( \operatorname{mod} M) - j2\pi q v_0( \operatorname{mod} N)}$? Have you not tried figuring out what values of $u_0$ and $v_0$ will give you linearly independent rows?

Comment: I think you're missing an m and n in your result but I managed to derive it. The question is what is the rank for a general $u_0$ and $v_0$. I can only really see the trivial case where $u_0$ and $v_0$ are multiples of M and N where the rank is of course zero.

Comment: What you have is a plane wave. I've never considered a plane wave as a linear system before, so I'm not sure how to approach it but suspect the answer is one. (Your example gives a matrix of all ones, which has rank one not zero.) There's probably a theorem from linear algebra that can be used to prove this. For instance, if $F$ is the column-wise DFT and $G$ the row-wise DFT, then $FHG$ will be a matrix of all zeros except for a $1$ at the frequency of the wave. Since the DFT matrices are full-rank, the rank of $H$ must be 1. Not sure about this, so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: I thought a bit more about it. If I just consider the $m$ dimension, we have something of the form $H[m] = e^{i2\pi *m/A}$. So the matrix entries look like the following $1, e^{i2\pi *1/A}, e^{i2\pi *2/A}...$ The rank corresponds to when $m=A$ because after that, the next entries cycle around. Is this the answer?

Comment: I don't think so. Aren't all rows just phase-shifted copies of one another? Try picking any row and see if you can find a scalar that will make it match another row. If so, then that row is redundant. I'm pretty sure you'll find that all but one row is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose any two rows, say $m = m_i$ and $m = m_j$. Their values are

$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{row} \, i & : & e^{j2\pi m_i u_0 / M }e^{j2\pi n v_0 / N } & , & n = 0,1,\dots,N-1 \\
\mathrm{row} \, j & : & e^{j2\pi m_j u_0 / M }e^{j2\pi n v_0 / N } & , & n = 0,1,\dots,N-1
\end{align}
$$

If we multiply row $j$ by $e^{j2\pi (m_i-m_j)u_0/M}$, then the two rows will be equal. Thus, the RREF form of the matrix will contain only one non-zero row and the rank of the linear system is $1$.